# How to summarize the values by their latest timestamps using QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I've tried to do it using something like:

```
=UNIQUE(query(J2:L,"select J, K, MAX(L) where K matches 'Pending' or K matches 'Finished' group by J, K, L"))
```

but it doesn't get the unique values, as the expected result shows:

[image]

Here is a test [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one QUERY you can't limit to one result per item in J. One option is to use a formula like this:

```
=filter({unique(J3:J),byrow(unique(J3:J),LAMBDA(each,query(J3:L,"Select K,L where J = "&each&" order by L desc limit 1",0)))},unique(J3:J)<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks. Got lost pretty early in the formula, given its abstractions. It doesn't return the rows containing the latest entries, though.

Comment: It was "order by L" sorry!

Comment: ...and ```Desc``` instead. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm glad you could work it out despite myself!

Answer (score 1):

added solution [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=827793787)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(J3:J,J3:J<>"")),1,1),LAMBDA(jx,vlookup(jx,{SORT(J:L,3,0)},{1,2,3},))))`

[image]